# can't set radio button to required in django

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-forms

I have the following radio button html using django widget tweaks (i do not have to use this library and open to using whatever method works):

```
{% for choice in seeking_form2.disaster_recovery %}
                          <div class="radio radio-primary radio-inline">
                           {{ choice.tag|attr:"required" }}
                            <label for='{{ seeking_form2.disaster_recovery.auto_id }}_{{ forloop.counter0 }}'>{{ choice.choice_label }}</label>
                          </div>
                          {% endfor %}
```

Which should create radios that look like this:

```
<input id="id_disaster_recovery" name="disaster_recovery" type="radio" value="2" required>
```

My model looks like:

```
BOOL_CHOICES = ((True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No'))
disaster_recovery = models.BooleanField(choices=BOOL_CHOICES, default=False, )
```

My form looks like:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {
            'disaster_recovery': forms.RadioSelect(), 
        }
```

I get the error:

> 'SafeText' object has no attribute 'as_widget'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand your problem correctly, you should be overriding this in the form, rather than at the template, or the models.

```
class MyModelForm(..):
    disaster_recovery = forms.ChoiceField(choices=BOOL_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(), required=True) #Default is dropdown
```

Now, you could simplify your HTML to render the radiobuttons.

[Some more context on this can be found here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/#widgets-inheriting-from-the-select-widget)

To add the HTML required attribute, to your existing form, you can do:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {
            'disaster_recovery': forms.RadioSelect(attrs={"required": "required"}), 
        }
```

Here is the relevant [documentation on the custom attributes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs)

Comment: Even with this solution, how can I add the "required" attribute to the input?

Comment: Just add a `required=True` to the form attribute. (see the edit)

Comment: This is different that the boolean HTML attribute required: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Comment: Oohh. sorry. I understood the question wrong. . Check the edit.